# re-order first and second column based on third while keeping it intact

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

Im trying to order two columns based on a third. Maybe it's more like reordering.

Dummy data

```
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(c('kex','id1A','id3B'),
                          c('sex','id1B','id1A'),
                          c('hex','id2A','id3C'),
                          c('flex','id3A','id1B'),
                          c('snex','id3B','ID2A'),
                          c('dex','id3C','id3A')))
```

The items in the first column are associated to the items in the second column. The third column includes the same items as the second, but in a different order. I want to (re)order the first and second column based the third while keeping its order intact. It's basically re-shuffling the second (and first on the fly) column so it (they) matches the third.

The output would look like this;

```
>df
V1   V2   V3
1 snex id3B id3B
2  kex id1A id1A
3  dex id3C id3C
4  sex id1B id1B
5  hex id2A ID2A
6 flex id3A id3A
```

Any pointer would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `rank` and `cbind`

```
> cbind(df[rank(df$V3), -3], V3=df$V3)
    V1   V2   V3
5 snex id3B id3B
1  kex id1A id1A
6  dex id3C id3C
2  sex id1B id1B
3  hex id2A ID2A
4 flex id3A id3A
```

Comment: Thanks! Really nice. However, on my real data, not sure why... if it's the complexity of the identifiers, but the whole string quite often dont match... like these. Any idea why it can be?

`Aplysina_cauliformis_KF286041 | Aplysina_cauliformis_KF286023`
`Aplysina_cauliformis_KF286023 | Aplysina_cauliformis_KF286044`

Answer (score -3):

Maybe

```
cbind(df[with(df,order(V3)),c(1,2)], df[,3])
    V1   V2 df[, 3]
2  sex id1B    id3B
4 flex id3A    id1A
5 snex id3B    id3C
6  dex id3C    id1B
1  kex id1A    ID2A
3  hex id2A    id3A
```

Comment: Maybe not.  Did you test this?

Comment: Ok, `order` is not case sensitive, so this is not the solution.